# How do I find all the types used by an object and it's members recursively?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to use the DataContractJsonSerializer to serialize and deserialize a c# object that contains an object[] of differing types.

I need to find all the types used by the XmlRequest and the objects in it's object[] so I an pass the list of Types to the DataContractJsonSerializer.

The object[] in XmlRequest will contain different types. TypeX, TypeY, string, int, TypeZ

```
var sr = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(XmlRequest), knownTypes);
```

Xml Request Class:

```
[DataContract]
    public class XmlRequest
    {
        [DataMember]
        public object[] Parameters { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: At this point I don't know that it is possible without an instance of the object already populated with other objects. The "Type" is object[], so there's no way to find the Types of objects in the object array using only the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this through configuration instead of trying to discover these items at runtime.

```
<system.runtime.serialization>
        <dataContractSerializer>
            <declaredTypes>
                <add type="Whatever.XmlRequest, Whatever, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
                    <knownType type="WhateverLibary.Parameter, WhateverLibary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                </add>
            </declaredTypes>
        </dataContractSerializer>
    </system.runtime.serialization>
```

Answer (score 2):

I see the answer to the question, as written, but want to explore further.

Are you trying to genericize the XmlRequest so it can take one or more objects of a single type, as in:

```
Object[] ary = new Object[] { new MyObject(), new MyObject() };
```

Or are you actually throwing multiple types into an array, as in:

```
Object[] ary = new Object[] { new MyObject(), new MyOtherObject() };
```

If you are doing the former, consider using Generics. For a Request, not the most heterogenous solution, but XmlRequest is a wonderful way to load an object, an array of a single type, etc.

Serialization is easier if you are doing the former and use generics and does not require the heavier "check each type" approach, as the Parameters array is strongly typed.

Comment: Unfortunately the objects in the object[] are different as in your second example.

Comment: Then Jason's answer is probably a better starting point. :-( I currently use generics for services, which allows the default JSON serialization in WCF 4, so I wanted to suggest that route, if possible, as it is an easier "row to hoe".

Answer (score 0):

```
public void CollectTypes(Type type, HashSet<Type> types)
{
    if (types.Contains(type)) return;
    types.Add(type);

    foreach (FieldInfo fi in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        if (!fi.IsInitOnly)
        {
            CollectTypes(fi.FieldType, types);
        }
    }

    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        if (pi.CanWrite && pi.CanRead)
        {
            CollectTypes(pi.PropertyType, types);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
object[] parameters = ....;
HashSet<Type> types = new HashSet<Type>();
foreach(object p in parameters)
{
    if (p != null)
    {
      CollectTypes(p.GetType(), types)
    }
}

var sr = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(XmlRequest), types.ToArray());
```

The check if a given member is read-only is not required if the deserializer is able to write read-only members.

Comment: I tried this and realized why this is not possible. The type is object[]. we have no way of getting the type information of the objects in the object[] from just the type declaration.